# How do I make a bare react native project?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm coding using react native and I would like to start a bare react native project that doesn't use expo. I'm trying to use dependencies that don't use expo like the react native inappbrowser. Can someone help me?

I started a react native project but that was with expo. I tried to eject expo from the project but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot eject Expo from a project that created by Expo.

If you want to start a bare react native project that doesn't use expo, try to use [React Native CLI](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native) to create a new one.

Comment: Take a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843497/how-to-eject-expo-project-to-native-code