# How to use the react-native-share library to share to Instagram Stories?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript, react-native

How to use the react-native-share library to share to Instagram Stories? Why does it always redirect to another application every time onPress is triggered, even though it is according to the documentation?

```
import Share from 'react-native-share';

const shareOptions = {
    stickerImage: 'data:image/png;base64,<imageInBase64>', //or you can use "data:" link
    backgroundBottomColor: '#fefefe',
    backgroundTopColor: '#906df4',
    social: Share.Social.INSTAGRAM_STORIES,
    appId: 'your_fb_app_id' 
  };

Share.shareSingle(shareOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add intent in XML file

Add intent to `androidManifest.xml` file

```
  <queries>
      <!-- Specific apps you share to -->
      <package android:name="com.instagram.android" />
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
      </intent>
    </queries>
```

Update your `shareOptions` with my `shareOptions`

```
let options = {
        title: "APP",
        message: "",
        url: "Url is here",
        subject: "",
        social: Share.Social.INSTAGRAM_STORIES, // or Share.Social.INSTAGRAM,
        forceDialog: true,
        type: "mime type",  //it is required for Instagram
    }
```

Comment: how to set it on app.json ?

ios & android

Comment: have you used expo?

Comment: For expo we use expo sharing

Comment: Yes, used in Expo, I don't know how to configure Expo-sharing for Instagram. do you have an example ?

Comment: But you can also use react-native-share in expo, eject the project in expo check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76570319/11762907

Comment: yes, but `queries` are not generated in `androidManifest.xml` after running `npx expo prebuild`

Comment: Have you added it properly in the xml file?

Comment: show me  your XML file if you can

Comment: I already know how to add custom `queries` to `AndroidManifest.xml` at Expo

Comment: OK, Is your problem solved?